# Embed/overlay velocity vectors on a contour plot using plotly in R

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have drawn contour plot using plotly package in R. Additionally, I have used QUIVER function using pracma package to generate velocity vectors. Now I would like to overlay velocity vectors on top of the contour plot. How can I do that? Since I have not found any QUIVER function in r-plotly, so used another package.

```
plot_ly(x=x,y=y,z=z,type="contour")   # contour plot using plotly package
quiver(x,y,u,v)                       # vector plot using pracma package
```

Now I would like to show both on the same plot.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: example code: 1) plot_ly(x=x,y=y,z=z,type="contour") # contour plot using plotly package 2) quiver(x,y,u,v) # vector plot using pracma package

now I would like to show both on the same plot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Read and include features from [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1), especially the part about reproducing and pasting your data.